# Why does one of the two programs cause "*** glibc detected *** double free or corruption" error while the other not?

Tags: c++, memory

According to valgrind, this problem is caused by the codes below.I want to remove the element in the list, which contains the same integer value as ref.

```
while(itr1!=list1.end())
{
 if(itr1->num==ref)
 {
  list1.erase(itr1);
 }
 else
 {itr1++;}
}
```

list1 is an STL list, the type of list element is NODE, which is a structrue. num is one of the integer element in NODE . itr1 is an iterator of list1. ref is an integer value.

---

But after I replace with the codes below, it's correct

```
for(;itr1!=list1.end();itr1++)
{
 if(itr1->num==ref)
 {
  list1.erase(itr1);
  itr1--;
 }
}
```

I really couldn't see the difference between the two snippets.

I don't know whether you can figure out the problem with incomplete codes. If you need, I can post all the program. Thanks!

Comment: Neither is correct. It should be either `list1.erase(itr1++)` or `itr1 = list1.erase(itr1)`. But really you should be using `remove_if`: `list1.remove_if([ref](Foo const & x) { return x.num == ref; });`

Comment: Your iterator points to an element you've just erased, so technically ++ or -- from it is not allowed (I think).

Comment: I like `itr1 = list1.erase(itr1)`, it's very neat. Code of the loop could become `itr1 = (itr1->num == ruf) ? list1.erase(itr1) : itr1 + 1;` I suppose that's the code of `remove_if` :)

Comment: Hey, @Antonio. I think itr1+1 will not work. I onced used this expression and compiler told me "no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘itr + 1’". I think you should use itr1++

Comment: @Michael You are right, I am disappointed! :) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ But they filled the void in c++11 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After an `erase` the iterator of the removed element is invalidated. The second code works because of luck, though this is undefined behaviour and the code should be considered buggy.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I should change list1.erase(itr1); to itr1=list1.erase(itr1);. This way, it works.

Comment: You didn't finish the comment, but the link says that the iterator at `position` is invalidated. This is your `itr1`. So `itr1--` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I misunderstood the description, "An iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element erased by the function call." I even didn't notice this is a return value. :). silly mistake. (from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/)

Comment: `All iterators for elements after are invalidated` That's [not correct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/): Iterators, pointers and references referring to elements removed by the function are invalidated.
**All other iterators, pointers and references keep their validity.**

Comment: Ok, now I can give you your +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not exiting the loop after erasing the element. [Iterators pointing to an erased element are invalidated](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/#validity).

```
while(itr1!=list1.end())
{
 if(itr1->num==ref)
 {
  list1.erase(itr1);
  break;
 }
 else
 {itr1++;}
}
```

Have you considered using [remove_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove_if/)?

It might be less efficient if you know that you have only one element with that value in the list (remove_if search all occurrencies).

Comment: It seems remove_if could work better for my situation. I'll have a try. thx.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, just be careful to use [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove_if/) and not [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/), they are quite different! The first erases the elements, the second only push them at the end of the container.

Answer (score -1):

Iterators are really pointers in disguise. When you erase through an iterator, that iterator becomes invalid; it is analogous to doing a `delete` or `free()`.  The solution is the same as in classic C code:

```
// Classic C code for removing all nodes matching 
// key_to_delete from doubly-linked list:
while (itr != list->null_node)
{
   node *next = itr->next; // Calculate next node now, while itr is valid!

   if (itr->data == key_to_delete) {
      itr->prev->next = itr->next;
      itr->next->prev = itr->prev;
      list_node_free(itr);
   }

   itr = next; // Advance to previously calculated next node
}
```

The same concept in C++ with list container:

```
while (itr1 != list1.end())
{
   std::list<whatever>::iterator next = itr1;  // calculate next iterator now
   next++;                                     // while itr1 is valid

   if (itr1->num == ref)
   {
     list1.erase(itr1);
   }

   itr1 = next;
}
```

The `erase` operation on a list iterator only invalidates that iterator (and all copies of it). It does not invalidate iterators pointing to other parts of the list. This is why the value of `next` survives the erasure and can be used.